# How to get the current ViewContext in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

So I've got a bit of data that I'm poking into `ViewContext.ViewData` from _ViewStart.vbhtml.

Something like:  `ViewContext.ViewData("__Stuff") = stuffObject`

Now from a class that has no concept of Views or MVC or anything web-framework related, I'd like to grab the current ViewContext.

Similar to how you can do `HttpContext.Current`, I'd like some way of asking for the current `ViewContext`.

So far my searches through `HttpContext` have not yielded results.

*Yes, I am aware that I can inject the ViewContext from the View that needs this data.  But that is less desirable than having a function that can find it without this injection.*

Comment: Do you need that data to remain in session across multiple post/gets?

Comment: @Mr.Young: I do not.  The ViewContext.ViewData is set each time the _ViewStart page is rendered.  There is far more going on in this function than I have posted in my question - but I tried to simplify it down to the bare essentials to answer the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may be out of luck.  Typically, as you probably know, the view is the end of the line.  Most components do not know what view is going to run until it does.  I know you are reluctant to pass the information in, but maybe you can use something like an `actionfilter` to add the information to the HttpContext.

```vb
Public Class ViewDataInjectionAttribute
    Inherits ActionFilterAttribute

    Public Overrides Sub OnActionExecuted(ctx As ActionExecutedContext)

        Dim result = TryCast(ctx.Result, ViewResult)
        If result IsNot Nothing Then
            HttpContext.Current.Items("viewData") = result.ViewData
        End If

        MyBase.OnActionExecuted(ctx)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Then, you can apply the filter at the action, controller, or even globally.

Comment: Nice thought @Rob.  I know what I'm trying to do is not something one would traditionally/typically do.  And I may opt for a different architecture in the future.  This one is kind of organic - trying to shoehorn this feature into a large existing code base.  So thank you for the Attribute idea.. I hadn't thought of that before.

Comment: Taking a second to think about the attribute though.. Attributes are typically applied to the Controller Action.  The View, being kind of a text file - mashup of html and code, doesn't have a place to apply attributes as far as I am aware.  And the Action doesn't have to return the same view for all code paths.  You could conditionally return different views.  Something to ponder over.  Thanks again.

Comment: Agreed you cannot put an action filter on a view, But, you were working on the _viewstart which hits every view.  An action filter can be added globally to achieve the same result.